# Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. jest/enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I even tried it by giving classnames and removing div and adding it back. Can somene help?
//Page1.js

```
 <div  className="email" >
      <MyInput className="input1" name="email" type="email" onChange={formikProps.handleChange}/>
      </div>
```

//Page1.test.js

```
describe("testing email",()=>{
    test("email check",()=>{
        let wrapper  = shallow(<Page1/>)
        wrapper.find('MyInput[name="email"]').simulate('onChange', {target: {
            name: 'email',
            value: 'ale@gmail.com'
        }})
        expect(wrapper.state('email')).toEqual('ale@gmail.com')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `simulate` has to be the event name to be simulated not the name of the event handler.

```js
wrapper.find('MyInput[name="email"]').simulate('change', {target: {
            name: 'email', value: 'ale@gmail.com' }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Shallow doesn't render child components. It will render just the react wrapper. For testing events and interactions, use `mount`. Also you can use `console.log(wrapper.debug())` to see the content of wrapper. It will help you to identify the problem